# Different behavior in passing the same props in 2 components in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am passing the `chatAppProps` from `App.js` --> `ChatFeed.js` .

From `ChatFeed.js` , I am passing the same props to two components, `MessageForm.js` and `MyMessage.js` .

But I am able to use `{...props}` in `MessageForm.js` but not in `MyMessage.js`. I want to use `{ chatId } = props` from the props.

Here are the files.

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import { ChatEngine } from "react-chat-engine";
import ChatFeed from "./components/ChatFeed";
import LoginForm from "./components/LoginForm";

function App() {
  const project_id = process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID;

  if (!localStorage.getItem("username")) {
    return (
    <div className="w-full"><LoginForm /></div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <ChatEngine
      height="100vh"
      userName={localStorage.getItem("username")}
      userSecret={localStorage.getItem("password")}
      projectID={project_id}
      renderChatFeed={(chatAppProps) => <ChatFeed {...chatAppProps} />}
      onNewMessage={() =>
        new Audio(
          "https://chat-engine-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/click.mp3"
        ).play()
      }
    />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ChatFeed.js**

```
import React from "react";
import MessageForm from "./MessageForm";
import MyMessage from "./MyMessage";
import TheirMessage from "./TheirMessage";

const ChatFeed = (props) => {
  const { chats, activeChat, messages, userName } = props; 

  const chat = chats && chats[activeChat];

  const renderReadReceipts = (message, isMyMessage) =>
      //some funvtion
    );

  const renderMessage = () => {
    const keys = Object.keys(messages);

    return keys.map((key, index) => {
      const message = messages[key];

      const lastMessageKey = index === 0 ? null : keys[index - 1];
      const isMyMessage = userName === message.sender.username;
      

      return (
        <div key={`msg_${index}`} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          <div className="message-block">
            {isMyMessage ? (
              <MyMessage {...props} message={message} /> <!--Passing Props here but NOT working -->
            ) : (
              <TheirMessage
                message={message}
                lastMessage={messages[lastMessageKey]}
              />
            )}
          </div>
          <div
            style={{
              marginRight: isMyMessage ? "18px" : "0px",
              marginLeft: isMyMessage ? "0px" : "68px",
            }}
            className="read-receipts"
          >
            {renderReadReceipts(message, isMyMessage)}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  if (!chat) return <div />;

  return (
    <div className="chat-feed">
      <div className="chat-title-container">
        <div className="chat-title">{chat?.title}</div>
        <div className="chat-subtitle">
          <strong className="font-bold">Members:</strong> {chat.people.map((item) => `${item.person.username}, `)}
        </div>
      </div>
      {renderMessage()}
      <div style={{ height: "100px" }} />
      <div className="message-form-container">
        <MessageForm {...props} chatId={activeChat} />  <!--Passing Props here AND working -->
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatFeed;
```

**MessageForm.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { sendMessage, isTyping } from "react-chat-engine";

const MessageForm = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const { chatId, creds } = props;
  //This is WORKING here , chat Id is seen here

  console.log("from message form= "+chatId);
  

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const project_id = process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID;



  const authObject = {
    "Project-ID": project_id,
    "User-Name": username,
    "User-Secret": password,
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); //to not do a browser refresh
    const text = value.trim();

    if (text.length > 0) sendMessage(creds, chatId, { text });

    setValue("");
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    isTyping(props, chatId);
  };

  const handleUpload = (e) => {
    sendMessage(creds, chatId, { files: e.target.files, text: "" });
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("username", username);
    localStorage.removeItem("password", password);
    window.location.reload();
  }

  return (
    <form className="message-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <input
          className="message-input"
          placeholder="Send a Message ..."
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-row">
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="upload_button">
          <span className="image-button">
            <i className="far fa-image"></i>
          </span>
        </label>
        <input
          type="file"
          multiple={false}
          id="upload_button"
          className="hidden"
          onChange={handleUpload}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="send-button">
          <i className="far fa-paper-plane send-icon"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="me-auto">
      <button onClick={handleLogout}  className="send-button">
          <i className="fas fa-power-off send-icon"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default MessageForm;
```

**MyMessage.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { deleteMessage } from "react-chat-engine";

const MyMessage = ({ message }, props) => {
  const { chatId, creds } = props;
  // NOT working, chatId shows undefined
  
  console.log("from mymessage = "+chatId)  
 
  

  const handleDelete = (msgID) => {
    deleteMessage(props, chatId, msgID);
  };

  if (message?.attachments?.length > 0) {
    return (
      <img
        src={message.attachments[0].file}
        alt="message_attachment"
        className="message-image"
        style={{ float: "right" }}
      />
    );
  }



  return (
    <div
      className="message"
      style={{
        float: "right",
        marginRight: "18px",
        color: "white",
        backgroundColor: "#3B2A50",
      }}
    >
      {message?.text}
      <span>
        <button onClick={()=>handleDelete(message?.id)} className="bg-black text-red-800">
          Del
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyMessage;
```

I don't know why they are beating differently even after passing the same props, and destructuring in the same way in respective components.

Answer (score 1):

Props are passed as the first argument to your component. In your MyMessage component, you are only destructuring the message off the props. Do this instead:

```js
const MyMessage = (props) => {
  const { chatId, creds, message} = props;
  // ...
```

Or better yet:

```js
const MyMessage = ({chatId, creds, message}) => {
  // ...
```

Comment: My bad, Silly mistake, I didn't noticed that. Thanks bro